# Window with SysMonthCal32 class doesn't respond to WM_SETFONT

Tags: c++, winapi, common-controls

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. I have a functionality in my CDialog-based MFC app to increase the font in some common controls. It is done by sending them [WM_SETFONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-setfont) message with a larger font:

```
//No error checks for brevity

HFONT hFnt = (HFONT)::SendMessage(hCtrlWnd, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);

LOGFONT lfFont;
::GetObject(hFnt, sizeof(lfFont), &lfFont);

BOOL bPositive = lfFont.lfHeight >= 0;
long nFontSz = abs(lfFont.lfHeight);
nFontSz += nFontDelta;
lfFont.lfHeight = bPositive ? nFontSz : -nFontSz;

HFONT hNewFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&lfFont);

::SendMessage(hCtrlWnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hNewFont, TRUE);

//Need to DeleteObject hNewFont when control gets a new font or is destroyed
```

This works for most controls except the DateTime picker (or to be more precise, its month-calendar, `SysMonthCal32` window class.)

Here's a screenshot on Windows XP, where it works as expected:

Normal magnification:

[image]

Enlarged:

[image]

But here's what I get on Windows 10, normal magnification:

[image]

And (supposed to be) enlarged, but isn't:

[image]

So why is it working on XP and stops, starting from Vista onward?

Comment: This is only a guess, but it might simply not respond (for gui consistness reasons) to WM_SETFONT; Try changing it's visual theme.

Comment: The font can be changed by removing the theme in DTN_DROPDOWN, but the calendar must be resized, from my tests. 
A big font on Windows 10 :  [Test DTP font](https://i.ibb.co/QXqTcTd/DTP-2.jpg)

Comment: @Castorix: Hmm, interesting, Thanks. Can you show how you removed its theme? Also what would happen if you add it back after resizing? (Also, I'm assuming that you resize it after retrieving its ideal size with `MCM_GETMINREQRECT`, right?) If it's easier, I have an email addr in my profile. Thanks.

Comment: The test I did : I changed the font with DateTime_SetMonthCalFont after its creation, then in
 DTN_DROPDOWN I get the MonthCal handle with DTM_GETMONTHCAL, I remove the theme with SetWindowTheme(hWndMonthCal, L"", L"");
 and I resize the container window with MoveWindow(GetParent(hWndMonthCal), 0, 0, 600, 400, TRUE);
 (600, 400 is for testing, those values must in fact be big enough to force a resize)

Comment: @Castorix" what happens if you then call `SetWindowTheme(hWnd, L"EXPLORER", NULL)` on it after resizing?

Comment: The original theme comes back with the original theme font...

Comment: @Castorix: and does the font size remain large?

Comment: No, the new font is only used when the control has no theme (like when it is created with CC. v. 5)

Comment: @Castorix: yeah, thanks, It looks like there's some kinda bug in the `SysMonthCal32` WndProc logic when dealing with themes and fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using ComCtl32.dll version 6 which uses the Visual Styles API.
This means that most text is drawn by either [`DrawThemeText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemetext) or [`DrawThemeTextEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemetextex).
Both of these functions use the font specified by the `HTHEME` argument.

To change the font you could either change the window's theme using `SetWindowTheme` or  use a version of ComCtl32.dll prior to version 6.

The handling of `WM_SETFONT` and `WM_GETFONT` seems to be for keeping compatibility with programs that use these messages to store their font. They are not actually used for drawing.

Comment: Hmm ... except that every other control that has visual themes works with the `WM_SETFONT`, except that one.

Comment: There are [dozens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/individual-control-info) of controls, of which only about half support changing the font when drawn with visual styles. The month calendar class doesn't seem to be one of them. Subclassing the control and temporarily hooking `DrawThemeText` during `WM_PAINT` might also work.